# How can configure Entity Framework within my code?

Tags: c#, wpf, app-config

I have a very small WPF executable that I want to be stand-alone. I've wittled the external dependencies down to a single MyApp.exe.config file. It needs this because I am using Entity Framework. Is there anyway I can configure this in code so that it can be compiled into my executable?

Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
    </startup>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Windows.Interactivity" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
            </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
            <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I agree and have cast a re-open vote on this.

Comment: If you are using EF6, This article has ifnormation on Code-Based configuration: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699

Comment: Thank you! I am so tired of these zealots. I searched stack overflow before asking my question. They close my question without even reading it or giving an explanation. Stack overflow is not a place to find answers, any more.

Comment: @Jordan: My bad. I must say I find your post very confusing. You are referring to 'stand alone' and the list of assemblies you have. I agreed on the question being duplicate.

Comment: I agree with patrick, if you are not tying to merge assemblies, what are you trying to do? Are asking how to get the information set up in the App.Config to be configured via code instead of in a external xml file?

Comment: I am trying to make my executable stand-alone. But my question was about my App.Config file. Not about assemblies. I think @JohnKoerner answered my question, but I'm not sure.

Comment: But what do you mean then? The app.config is in the application right? What do you want more?

Comment: @Jordan: Tip for the next time something like this happens, just ping me using `@username`.

Comment: First, I am sorry for my outburst. It just makes me furious that more times than not, my question gets posted as duplicate when it has nothing to do with the supposed duplicate. It has happened too often. I don't want to have an external App.Config file. I want to configure Entity Framework from within my code.

Comment: @Jordan: Then just post that part of the app.config. All that other code makes it confusing. Also your text isn't as clear as your last comment.

Comment: But what do you mean by *stand-alone*?

Comment: A single executable file. I've already worked out the external dll dependencies. I just needed to figure out how to remove the need for an external App.config.

Comment: I see what is going on. People are reading my header only. I'll have to change it.

Answer (score 3):

The link provided in the comments by John Koerner solved my problem. For anyone who is looking for the solution here is the code that I used:

```
public class MyDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyDbConfiguration()
    {
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"));
        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlClient", SqlProviderServices.Instance);
        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0", SqlCeProviderServices.Instance);
    }
}
```

I just included this object in the same assembly as my DbContext. It worked wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot configure this in code, but you can you ILMerge to merge the EF DLL (and any others you might need) into your exe.  [Here is an example of how to use ILMerge](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ILMerge.aspx)

Comment: Not at all what I am looking for.